# Spotlight only working from the finder

Tags: spotlight

When I search from the finder spotlight is working as expected.

When pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and entering the same query I only get results from Safari's history.

**Edit**

The index is OK and the results are correct when searching with the Finder and with `mdfind` on the command line. Is only the spotlight window (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) that is not working.

**Edit 2**

Rebuilding the index does not change the behaviour

Any hint on how could I solve the problem?

Comment: what happens if Safari is closed when you run command?

Comment: @jmh The same even with Safari closed

Answer (score 1):

You have some or more items disabled in **System Preferences / Spotlight**, I was able to replicate your issue completely by turning off everything but *Bookmarks & History*. Check the items you want searched and see if that shows documents and other things as well.

[image: Spotlight preferences]